# add hook restricted only to either plugins or themes?

Tags: hooks, actions

I'm writing a plugin and I want to create two hooks like the following:

```
add_action( 'myplugin/ready_for_theme', array( __CLASS__, 'myfunction_for_themes' ) );
add_action( 'myplugin/ready_for_plugins', array( __CLASS__, 'myfunction_for_plugins' ) );
```

How to prevent themes to add actions to a specific hook and, viceversa, to prevent plugins to add actions on the theme's dedicated hook?

thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think you can't do that. Why do you want do that?

Answer (score 0):

Errm, you can't. And more importantly, why would you want to? The whole point of hooks is to open up an API to other developers!

You can use a singleton/static flags and/or private methods (called from a hooked public method) if you want to lock down how your plugin can be manipulated.

```
static function myfunction_for_themes() {
    if ( ! self::$_themes_run /* private static property */ ) {
         self::_private_method();

         self::$_themes_run = true;
    }
}
```

A plugin/theme could still unhook the above method, but they wouldn't be able to fire it more than once, nor can they call `self::_private_method()`.

Comment: I wanted that because I'm creating a functionality which can be used by both themes and plugins, but the implementation for ones or the others change a bit. So I just wanted to prevent mistakes and make the API easier for developers :). @TheDeadMedic thanks for your answer